# How to get 10 latest tweets from a user as strings?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, mgtwitterengine, tweets

I'm making an app and I only need Twitter integration to get the latest tweets from a user and display them in a TableView.

I tried using MGTwitterEngine but I get lots of errors. I'm guessing it wasn't made for iOS.

While we're at it, does anyone have a working iOS twitter client project? Later I'm planning to add the function to tap on of the TableCells to reply to that tweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MGTwitterEngine actually works pretty well in iOS.
You should be using this version by Ben Gottlieb: [Twitter+OAuth/MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone)

There's a working example in that code if I remember correctly.

Just make sure to get your twitter API key at this address:

https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll update you if it works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ben Gottlieb has a very straightforward, easily integratable implementation for Twitter access via OAuth: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Two people recommended the same framework. I'm guessing it's good. I'll update you if it works for me. :)